# Converter txt,docx,doc,para pdf usando Php

Tags: php, pdf

Tenho que fazer um script em PHP onde ele vai ler varios arquivos e transformar todos em PDF. Estou usando o FPDF mas estou com dificuldades na logica em fazer com que ele leia cada arquivo no meu diretorio e transforme em PDF. Alguem pode me dar uma luz?

```
<?php
//require('gerapdf.php');

 $pasta = 'C:\xampp\www\listar\pdf';
 $listar  = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($pasta);
 $recursivo = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($listar);


 foreach($recursivo as $obj){
     echo '<a href="'.$obj->getPathname().'">'.$obj->getFilename().'</a><br/>';

 }
```

Comment: Olá, bem vindo. Cole aqui o código que você está usando e qual erro está tendo, assim fica mais fácil ajudar. Também dê uma lida sobre como fazer boas perguntas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask